# I have a p-tag on top of a image. How come I can't set the background-color of the p-tag?

Tags: css

It appears as though the "background" of the p-tag is behind the image. See for example the t-tag with the content Projektnamn on top of the images here:

http://dev.nuagency.se/illustrators/beata-boucht/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `position:relative` in your `P` tag. write like this:

```
.mygallery p {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    color: black;
    margin: -50px 0 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```